# In mongodb how to get the below records

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My collection:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
        "baseUrl": "https://www.site1.com/",
        "score": 10 
        }, 
        {
            "baseUrl": "https://www.site2.com/",
            "score": 10
        }, 
        {
            "baseUrl": "https://www.site3.com/",
            "score": 10
        }, 
        {
            "baseUrl": "https://www.site4.com/",
            "score": 10
        }
    ],
    "date": "2020-05-06T18:30:00.000Z"
},{
    "data": [
        {
            "baseUrl": "https://www.site1.com/",
            "score": 10 
        }, {
            "baseUrl": "https://www.site2.com/",
            "score": 10
        }, {
            "baseUrl": "https://www.site3.com/",
            "score": 10
        }
    ],
    "date": "2020-05-04T18:30:00.000Z"
}
```

I want to display only those details which match this filter-array.

filter-array = ["https://www.site1.com","https://www.site4.com"]

My final output should be,

```
{
    "data": [{
        "baseUrl": "https://www.site1.com/",
        "score": 10 
    }, {
        "baseUrl": "https://www.site4.com/",
       "score": 10
    }],
    "date": "2020-05-06T18:30:00.000Z",
    "__v": 0
    "_id":5eb5551504088f82ed184172
},
{
    "data": [{
        "baseUrl": "https://www.site1.com/",
        "score": 10 
    }],
    "date": "2020-05-04T18:30:00.000Z",
    "__v": 0
    "_id":5eb55515040s182ed184172
}
```

When I use $elematch it just returns only the first occurrence of the match.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      date: 1,
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: {$in: ["$$this.baseUrl", ["https://www.site1.com/", "https://www.site4.com/"]] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dGuVpd_gyaC)